# Connection Pool hanging with java multi threaded program

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, connection-pooling, ojdbc

I have a 24/7 java application(jdk1.5.0_19) which is multi threaded that uses OJDBC5 as the communication for oracle 11g (11.2.0.3). After verifying the contents of the thread, each thread calls a callable statement to be prepared then executes to insert data to table. Now at initialization there are a Total JDBC 20 Connections. For some time it goes really well no problems.

But recently there was an instance where it just hanged up during execution of the callable statement in DB.

```
2017-02-06 13:03:39,855 [Thread-1] INFO  QCCOM_SocketWorker run  - Worker thread launched.
2017-02-06 13:03:39,856 [Thread-1] INFO  QCCOM_Socket recvMessage  
2017-02-06 13:03:39,856 [Thread-1] INFO  QCCOM_SocketWorker recvRequest 
2017-02-06 13:03:39,856 [Thread-1] INFO  ProcessHandler invoke  
2017-02-06 13:03:39,856 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  HandlerValidator validateRequest 
2017-02-06 13:03:39,857 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  ProcessHandler process  - Processing request...
2017-02-06 13:03:39,857 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  JDBCHelper call  - Atempting to retrieve connection.
2017-02-06 13:03:39,857 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  JDBCHelper call  - Connection successfully retrieved
2017-02-06 13:03:39,857 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  JDBCHelper getConnection  - Conn : oracle.jdbc.driver.LogicalConnection@4f064f06
2017-02-06 13:03:39,858 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  JDBCServiceImpl insertBP  - Calling insert transaction stored procedure..
2017-02-06 13:03:43,856 [Thread-1] INFO  ProcessHandler invoke  - Worker Thread Timed out
2017-02-06 13:03:43,857 [Thread-1] DEBUG ProcessHandler invoke  - [java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:226), java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:100), ....ProcessHandler.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:114), com.qcom.qcm.qccom.QCCOM_SocketWorker.dispatch(QCCOM_SocketWorker.java:88), com.qcom.qcm.qccom.QCCOM_SocketWorker.run(QCCOM_SocketWorker.java:126)]
2017-02-06 13:03:43,857 [Thread-1] INFO  QCCOM_SocketWorker run  - Worker thread shutdown. 
2017-02-06 13:03:55,661 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  JDBCServiceImpl insertBP  - Callable Statement successfully closed!
2017-02-06 13:03:55,661 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  JDBCServiceImpl insertBP  - Connection successfully closed!
2017-02-06 13:03:55,662 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  ProcessHandler process  - Connection successfully closed!
```

Usually the transaction happens less than less than 200ms.

**2017-02-06 13:03:39,858 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  JDBCServiceImpl insertBP  - Calling insert transaction stored procedure..**

But in the instance above we have a hang on the execution of insert.

Please see code below (JDBCServiceImpl insertBP).

```
public synchronized void insertBP(String A, BigDecimal Num, Date Date) throws SQLException{
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    logger.info("Calling insert transaction stored procedure..");
    try{
        cs = (CallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("{"+sql+"}");
        cs.setString(1, tnxType);
        cs.setBigDecimal(2, Num);
        cs.setTimestamp(3, new Timestamp(Date.getTime()));

        cs.execute();
    } catch (SQLException sqlEx){           
        String strMessageContents = StringUtil.getFailedMessageContents(A, Num, Date);
        String strErrorMessage = "Failed to insert ";
        logger.fatal(strErrorMessage);
        aUtil.emailFatal;
        throw sqlEx;
    } finally {
        if (null!=cs){
            cs.close();
            logger.info("Callable Statement successfully closed!");
        }
        if (null!=conn){
            conn.close();
            logger.info("Connection successfully closed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow it hangs on cs.execute ... Then worker thread timeout comes along and kills the whole transaction but somehow it does not kill the already initiated callable statement.

I also have a code for fail over which kills the main connection, by this method the whole connection is killed resulting in successful killing.

**2017-02-06 13:03:55,661 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  JDBCServiceImpl insertBP  - Callable Statement successfully closed!**

Code is as follows

```
    if (Util.IsOffline){
    logger.info("App is Offline attempting to reestablish connection.");
    Util.destroyHelper();
    logger.info("Previous Connection Pool Destroyed...");
    logger.info("Reinitializing Connection Pool ...");
    try {
        AppJDBCHelper helper = AppJDBCHelper.getInstance();
        if (null != helper){
            logger.info("Connected to Schema: "+helper.getSchema());
            logger.info("Connection Pool initialized ...");
            Util.IsOffline = false;
            logger.info("App has reestablished connection.");
        }
        if (null == helper){
            logger.fatal("Failed to get database connection pool ...");
            Util.destroyHelper();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){
        logger.fatal("Failed to connect to database ...");
        logger.debug(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        System.out.println(" \n >>> ERROR: Failed to connect to database ..."); 
        Util.destroyHelper();
    }
}
```

Additional code for Util

```
public void destroyHelper(){
    AppJDBCHelper helper = null;
    try {
        helper = AppJDBCHelper.getInstance();
        helper.destroy();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.fatal(e);
        logger.debug(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }       
}
```

Additional code for AppJDBCHelper

```
public void destroy() throws SQLException{
    DBConnectionPool pool = new DBConnectionPoolImpl();
    pool.closeConnectionPool(ods);
    helper = null;
    logger.info("AppJDBCHelper destroy() success...");
}
```

These 2 machines are located in the same switch so there is less network friction.
and as checked there are no Network problems during that time. Also DB Listener is up and was ready to accept transactions.

So my main question here is what the heck is happening and the callable statement is hanging.

Comment: There has been hundreds if not thousands of bugs fixed in the JVM since April 2009. If you are getting strange behaviour, you might like to test it with a more recent JVM, or even the latest version of Java 5.0 released later that year.

Comment: Yeah understood I have proposed this as well but client still does not want to upgrade java version.

Comment: Understood. Can you come up with a work around if a fix doesn't seem obvious?

Comment: This actually happened last year also. So the fix was the fail over. after a few more timeouts the whole connection will disconnect and will reconnect.

Comment: but it happened 3 times in one day which is extremely unusual.

Comment: so the main work around was to restart the whole application. its ok now tho but they want the root cause and the possibility of this happening again reduced.

Comment: It is possibly a problem on the database side. Is it possible to try Java 8 for testing purposes. You might find it's not in Java at all.

Comment: In testing environment it doesn't happen. Only in production environment ... happens very rarely like glitches

Comment: I suspect the behaviour which triggers this is hard to reproduce.

Comment: that is true ... that is true ... possible java issue .. possible connection pool issue

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to go bottom up and check first if there were problems in the database. 
If you are on Oracle 11g, there is a good change you also have a license of [ASH](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13dba-1871177.html)

Check the database (or contact your DBA) with the following query, where you parametrise the time intrval and your connection pool DBUSER.
(If the problem was in past history switch to the table `dba_hist_active_sess_history` that contains longer time interval.

```
select  
SAMPLE_TIME, SQL_EXEC_ID, SESSION_ID, SESSION_SERIAL#, SQL_ID, TOP_LEVEL_SQL_ID, SQL_OPNAME,
PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID, EVENT, BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS, BLOCKING_SESSION, BLOCKING_SESSION_SERIAL#
select * from v$active_session_history
where sample_time between to_date('15022017 214500','ddmmyyyy hh24miss') and  to_date('15022017 215000','ddmmyyyy hh24miss')
and USER_ID in (select user_id from dba_users where username = '<your user name>')
order by session_id, SESSION_SERIAL#,SAMPLE_TIME;
```

Here is a sample output, simulating an `INSERT` blocked by a table lock.

```
SAMPLE_TIME                 SESSION_ID SESSION_SERIAL# SQL_ID        TOP_LEVEL_SQL_ID SQL_OPNAME   PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID EVENT                    BLOCKING_SESSION_STATUS BLOCKING_SESSION BLOCKING_SESSION_SERIAL#
--------------------------- ---------- --------------- ------------- ---------------- -----------  --------------------- -----------------------  ----------------------- ---------------- ------------------------
15.02.17 21:45:20,669000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:21,683000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:22,682000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:23,680000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:24,679000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:25,693000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:26,691000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283 
15.02.17 21:45:27,689000000         11           10976 gr2assvfzr2v7 6j87w7zmmzpsk    INSERT                       154744 enq: TM - contention    VALID                                 13                     4283
```

The inportant informaton is the timestamp, the session identification, the SQL operation (you expect INSERT) and the EVENT.
In my example you see EVENT `enq: TM - contention` that means the table is locked and the session can't perform the insert.
Of course you may see a different event - check the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/waitevents.htm#REFRN101) to resolve the problem cause.
Finally you see the *blocking status* and *blocking session* that may provide the solution why is the problem occured.

In case you don't see any suspicious evidence in the database (blocking or waiting states) proceede up and check logs of your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and will ask DBA to provide details. But as i recall they said there were no locks. will this display any other problems that may be present other than locking?

Comment: @Kyle ASH **is designed to troubleshoot such problems**. Espetially if they happen in the past. You see a periodic snapshot of all active sessions. It is not limited to blocking, you see sessions crunching CPU or waiting on I/O as well.  Check documetation, play with it in your development DB and *preferable* request access for the productive DB. Good lock!

Comment: Hi and thanks for the heads up. Anyway i've asked our DBA to run selected queries, and it gave out "no rows selected ". seems there were no problems during that time or it wasn't fully recorded.

Any other suggestions that i can check while DB team is checking on this?

Comment: Both views hold data only for a limited time. `v$active_session_history` contains only few hours, `dba_hist_active_sess_history` few days. Check the min(sample_time) to see if the data for your incident are available.

Comment: Feel free to up-wote if this answer is useful:)

Comment: just got back with DB team. seems data are not able to be collected anymore. any other suggestions?